# Is there a way to make bacon a decent substitute for pancetta in Italian dishes?

Tags: pork, italian-cuisine, bacon, pancetta

I live in a place where Pancetta is really hard to find, and when I do, it's completely overpriced. When I make some Carbonara or Gricia, both recipes from where I come from, I have to improvise it with good old bacon, but it never ends up the same as nonna did. So I ask, how can I make bacon a better substitute for pancetta?

Comment: It's kind of impossible to answer, IMO, nothing will taste the same as nonna do.

Comment: In the UK it's possible to buy both 'back' and 'streaky' (also I think sometimes called 'side'') bacon. The latter is somewhat like pancetta: both are belly part of the pig, both are cured. As user29568 says below you should buy unsmoked bacon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the same, but it can certainly work. Guanciale is a great substitute as well if you can find it.

I just made carbonara last week with bacon. I used [this recipe](https://www.americastestkitchen.com/recipes/7325-foolproof-spaghetti-carbonara). It came out pretty well. Using water in the initial cook makes the bacon come out a little more chewy.

Also, I use a zester on my pecorino, and it comes out grate that way.

Comment: If you think pancetta is hard to find and expensive, wait until you find some guanciale. I looked for years and finally found it in the Italian part of Providence, RI. Price was no object, it was for my dad, but it was stupid expensive.

Comment: Guanciale is another no go. Even more expensive than pancetta, but at least it's easier to find. I found out a good way to use bacon, though. As @myklbykl said, using water to cook it a little more evenly, letting it more crunchy, then I remove some of the fat it releases so that the pasta doesn't get too greasy

Answer (score 3):

You can substitute bacon for pancetta. The main difference between the two is that pancetta is unsmoked, so if you can find bacon that is unsmoked, go for that. If you only have access to smoked bacon, you can blanch the bacon before you use it in your recipe to reduce the smoky flavor. Check your local butcher they usually have pancetta, if you haven't already checked.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cured meats to use in either of these dishes would, traditionally, be guanciale or pancetta. Both of which are fairly different than your standard grocery store bacon. But I don't think that means you're entirely out of luck.

The main difference, although there are definitely others, between guanciale and pancetta is that guanciale comes from the jowl or cheek, and pancetta the pork belly. The main difference between bacon and the above two, though is that bacon is typically *smoked* in addition to being cured. This changes the flavor considerably, and I don't believe *smoked* bacon would make for a desirable flavor profile for carbonara, gricia, or anything else calling for the above ingredients.

**But what if you used unsmoked bacon?**

Unsmoked bacon, while substantially less common than the smoked version, might be possible to find, and should have a much more similar flavor profile to guanciale and pancetta. If you can't find it at your grocer, finding a local butcher and asking if they have, or could make some as a special order for you might be an option. According to [this link](https://www.livitaly.com/guanciale-vs-pancetta-vs-bacon/) you can discern whether it's smoked or unsmoked by the following method:

> A shopper can tell whether it’s been smoked by the condition of the flesh and the rind if it’s left on. If it’s been smoked, the rind is deep gold, and the flesh is deep pink. If it is unsmoked, the rind is white or cream-colored and the flesh is pale pink. Unsmoked or “green” is hard to come by.

If unsmoked bacon proves too hard to find, and you don't have access to a butcher willing to prepare some you have another easy option as well:

**Look at other cured meats**

- While distinctly inferior to carbonara made with guanciale or pancetta, I remember growing up that my mother would exclusively use ham to make carbonara as a cost cutting measure. Dice the ham up and prepare as usual.
- If available in your area, I've also heard of people using prosciutto for this purpose, although this is by no means a cost saving measure. At the very least, it's closer in flavor profile than bacon or ham.

If neither of the easy options suit your needs, you could try a few more labor intensive options as well:

**Widen your search on where you buy**

- If you really want an authentic flavor, this is your best bet. There are some companies that allow you to purchase fresh/cured meats online for delivery, and I know I've had good luck buying interesting cured meats at craft fairs or larger town's farmer's markets in the past. You might also be able to look for a community with a high amount of ethnic Italians or a larger city in general if you're willing to travel for it. In which case, I would recommend bringing an insulated cooler/ice packs along with you.
- If you have any Italian restaurants in the area, you could even speak to them and explain your predicament, ask them if they would be willing to order or share a certain amount of what they typically get with you, and pay for it. This will usually work best if you know someone who works there or worked there yourself at one point, but it's possible. You would likely need to order a larger quantity in these cases to be worth your while or to get the restaurant to agree.

**Or, if you're truly dedicated, consider making your own**

This is no small undertaking and not something I can personally advise on, but if you're determined to get an authentic flavor, don't mind waiting for it to cure, and are prepared to research the process this may be a possibility for you.

Comment: My mom would occasionally use a mix of bacon and ham when making carbonara.  There are people who harp on ‘traditional’, but this is poor people food… you use what was available and cheap.  (Although I would still try to stick with pork unless you’ve got dietary restrictions that prohibit it)

Answer (score 0):

Pancetta is bacon that has been hanged until it has lost 30% of it's weight. This process of hanging it after it has cured makes it possible to eat pancetta like ham. Without cooking it. If you are willing to cook the bacon before you use it then bacon is a fine substitute. It is pretty much the same thing, to be honest.

Answer (score -4):

Use old bacon, the ones you might find a little bit smelly but not rotten. Don't worry the cooking kills all bacteria. This works for me.

Comment: It doesn’t necessarily kill all bacteria, as some can survive at high heat.  More importantly, cooking doesn’t denature many of the toxins that the bacteria produced while they were still alive, and some toxins (like botulinum) can really mess you up, even in small amounts.